# Where can I find old alpha and beta versions of the Minecraft server software?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I can only find the alpha and beta clients and newer server versions.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any "official" sources. Due to the EULA restrictions about distributing the game, it's going to be difficult (if not impossible) to find any unofficial sources that has them all. If you're looking for a specific version, you can usually find them through google as many people put specific versions up on file sharing websites then distribute them through forums and YouTube. Good luck!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking about finding a resource that meets specific criteria.  That's a website recommendation, and will gather link-only answers that are vulnerable to link rot.  They also have no right answer, leading to voting based on popularity, not usefulness.

Comment: your best bet would be to ask people which used to host servers maybe they have the software laying around

Comment: This has every Server jar file that I know of... ranging from 1.8 Release to Pre-Alpha, This was made for personal use only

http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/discussion/173960-minecraft-jars